# How does ように function here?

Tags: grammar

The following is an excerpt from an e-mail conversation between me and my language partner.

For some pretext:
「大学の勉強の間」という文は、今のアンドレアスさんを知らない人にとっては、「過去を表す言葉」なのかどうかわかりません。

「私は過去に、移住者の子供にドイツ語を教えるアルバイトをしています」
とすれば、過去の経験であることがはっきりします。
さらに「過去に３年間」のようにすると、経験が一度ではなく、何年か続いたものであることがわかります。

The sentence in question:
さらに「過去に３年間」**のように**すると、**経験が一度ではなく、何年か続いたものであることが**わかります。

My attempt at translation:
"Furthermore, wenn you do it like 'in the past for three years', then one knows that it wasn't a one time experience and that it continued for many years."

My first issue lies with the use of のように here. I think it is used to express that "you VERB like NOMINAL PHRASE", right? I'm not really confident about my knowledge about the use of ように and wether the "in order to" semantics, comparable to VERBために, applies or the "like" semantics, comparable to みたいに, applies xD

My second issue lies with the connection of the 経験が一度ではなく and the 何年か続いたものである phrase which are ultimately both nominalized through こと. I am rather confident that I understood it right, but I wanted to ask for confirmation since I'm not 100% sure.

Answer (score 1):

Your knowledge about the use of ように is right. ように means "like" and する here means "write", "say", or "express". It can be said that this ように is used for giving an example out of some better expressions, like "Not only my way is the way to say it better, but there's many ways LIKE my way". のように書くと is a manner avoiding assertion compared to と書くと.

The answer to the second question is both nominalized, because this phrase starts from 経験が and ends with ものである. なく form cannot ends a phrase. You can use ない instead of なく to split the phrase: 経験が一度ではないこと、さらに何年か続いたものであることもわかります.